# Android Studio Build Error - Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0]

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am implementing FCM into my android project using Cordova
When I build my project I am getting error "Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
"
Here is my build.gradle file code inside app directory

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    google()
}

dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0' // Error generating line
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your repositories and dependencies in sequence manner which is suggested by Firebase.

Your build.gradle of project lavel should look like this, path of the file is just inside the project.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'Fabric URL'
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "JIT PACK URL"
        }
        maven {
            url 'MAVEN URL'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And after that your app level build.gradle should look like this, path of the file is inside the app. C:\Users\ABC\DEF\Project Name\app\build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    flavorDimensions "versionCode"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "App Package Name as "com.companyName.appName""
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 15
        versionName "1.0.12"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //  firebase push notifications
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.5.2'

    // firebase remote config
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If this not help for you you then try to change all the version of firebase and firebase remote config to latest version.
Because sometimes different version may cause problem.

Comment: thank you for your help. now I am using updated cordova FCM plugin mentioned https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated. And it is working fine now

Comment: And also I removed the last line "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" in build.gradle file inside app directory. Because in gradle version 4.4 and above it is not needed. It is written somewhere in file already. That's why it was throwing error. It is working fine now.